# Partial function application

Tags: elisp, functions

[`apply-partially`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) lets you create a new function by fixing the first `n` arguments of an existing function. Is there any way to achieve unrestricted partial function application, i.e., the ability to fix any `n` arguments of a function without the constraint that they be the first `n`? An example from another language is Python's [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#).

Comment: I'm less sure about this, but suspect [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) does this. It's implemented in [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) as [-cut](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-cut-rest-params)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea of transforming functions into different functions with specialized arguments has been elaborated upon in [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html).  There's an Emacs Lisp implementation of it in the very useful [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library where it's available as [-cut](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-cut-rest-params).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that I just wrote down:

```
(defun foobar (a b c)
  (list a "foo" b "bar" c))

(defun lame-partial (fun &rest plist)
  (let ((args (copy-seq
               (help-function-arglist fun t))))
    (dolist (k (cl-remove-if-not #'keywordp plist))
      (setq args (delq (intern (substring (symbol-name k) 1)) args)))
    `(lambda (,@args)
       (funcall
        ',fun
        ,@(mapcar
           (lambda (x)
             (or (plist-get plist (intern (format ":%S" x)))
                 x)) (help-function-arglist fun t))))))

(fset 'foobar-partial-1 (lame-partial #'foobar :b 7 :c (+ 2 2)))
(fset 'foobar-partial-2 (lame-partial #'foobar :c "derp" :b 0))

(mapcar #'foobar-partial-1 '(0 1 2))
;; => ((0 "foo" 7 "bar" 4) (1 "foo" 7 "bar" 4) (2 "foo" 7 "bar" 4))

(mapcar #'foobar-partial-2 '(0 1 2))
;; =>
;; ((0 "foo" 0 "bar" "derp")
;;  (1 "foo" 0 "bar" "derp")
;;  (2 "foo" 0 "bar" "derp"))
```

It's probably lame, but the approach is different from `-cut`.